# How to get a retina-ready image with a data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a following script where the logo file `"logo-sticky.png"` appears instead of file `"logo.png"` as soon as user scrolls.
I broke my head trying to find a solution of how to get the retina-ready files for my images.

Would appreciate any help!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.sticky-navbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.sticky-navbar').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

var navbarImg = $('.navbar-brand > img')
navbarImg.data('original', navbarImg.attr('src'))

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var stickyNav = $('.sticky-navbar');
    var isSticky = $(this).scrollTop() > 50;
    stickyNav.toggleClass('sticky', isSticky);
    navbarImg.attr('src', navbarImg.data(isSticky ? 'sticky' : 'original'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sticky-navbar hideme visible animated fadeInDown full-visible">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" data-sticky="assets/images/logo-sticky.png" />
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Depending on the browsers you need to support you can use `srcset`. That way you don't need any JS logic at all.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do I get it right that Android browsers don't support srcset at the moment?

Comment: No it's supported in all major Android browsers too: https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset. It's only IE, Blackberry and Opera where you'll have issues

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's great but unfortunately I'm afraid that won't work with my data-sticky attribute :(

Comment: It won't interfere with it

Comment: Are the two logos using a common design but with varying sizes or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the  attribute in your HTML rather than using JS.

There are different ways in this case to address the problem.

- Using different images for different screen sizes with [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) :

In this case it would just be classic responsive styling.

```
<img src="logo-400.png" 
  srcset="logo-200.jpg 200w, 
          logo-400.jpg 400w,
          logo-800.jpg 800w,
          logo-1200.jpg 1200w"
  data-sticky="assets/images/logo-sticky.png" 
/>
```

- Using a solo high quality image

Here as well we give the browser a default image and then he automatically defines which one to take depending on the screen size.

```
<img src="logo-1x.jpg" 
  srcset="logo-2x.jpg 2x, 
          logo-3x.jpg 3x"
  data-sticky="assets/images/logo-sticky.png" 
/>
```